# 400 error on django filefield model save

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-400

I'm using django 1.6.5 on python 2.7, and am trying to upload images with a form. My MEDIA_URL is '/uploads', MEDIA_ROOT='...../projectroot/uploads'.

My model:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/images')
```

My Form field:

```
images = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(), required=False)
```

My form saving:

```
image = self.cleaned_data['images']
picture = Picture(park=model, image=image)
picture.save()
```

I have tried setting the uploads folder permissions to 777 recursively, so django definitely has write access, but that didn't work. Somebody said the enctype on the form mattered, so I've set that to "multipart/form-data".

If it helps, only the actual saving creates the error (although that may have something to do with django just using lazy functions)

Comment: Do other views work?

Comment: do u have FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0644 in settings ?

Comment: Just tried that setting, didn't work. In answer to dan, this is the only file upload on the website so far, but no views give 400 errors on anything.